# Convert a String into an Array of Characters

Tags: php, arrays, string

In PHP, how do I convert:

```
$result = "abdcef";
```

into an array that's:

```
$result[0] = a;
$result[1] = b;
$result[2] = c;
$result[3] = d;
```

*Edited*

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You will want to use str_split().

```
$result = str_split('abcdef');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: Note that `str_split('')` returns non-empty array

Comment: Note: str_split() will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.

Answer (score 31):

Don't know if you're aware of this already, but you may not need to do anything (depending on what you're trying to do).

```
$string = "abcdef";
echo $string[1];
//Outputs "b"
```

So you can access it like an array without any faffing if you just need something simple.

Comment: This is the most efficient way to do it, since function calls incur more overhead.

Comment: Warning, doesn't work as expected when using multibyte characters!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the str_split() function:

```
$value = "abcdef";
$array = str_split($value);
```

If you wish to divide the string into array values of different amounts you can specify the second parameter:

```
$array = str_split($value, 2);
```

The above will split your string into an array in chunks of two.

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = "abcdef";
$result = str_split($result);
```

There is also an optional parameter on the str_split function to split into chunks of x characters.

Answer (score 4):

best you should go for "`str_split()`", if there is need to manual Or basic programming,

```
    $string = "abcdef";
    $resultArr = [];
    $strLength = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $strLength; $i++) {
        $resultArr[$i] = $string[$i];
    }
    print_r($resultArr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
)
```

Answer (score 4):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#refsect1-function.str-split-notes

> str_split() will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.

Use `mb_str_split()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you need multibyte support in an outdated version of PHP (a version below PHP7.4), then use `preg_split()` on an empty pattern with a unicode flag.  There is no need to slow down the regex engine with a capture group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZYUUV))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('//u', 'abcåäö', 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
    // or preg_split('/.\K/us', 'abcåäö', 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
    // or preg_split('/\X\K/u', 'abcåäö', 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

For any versions of PHP from 7.4 or higher, just use the dedicated function `mb_str_split()`.

```
mb_str_split('abcåäö')
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'å',
  4 => 'ä',
  5 => 'ö',
)
```

As a warning to researchers using other answers on this page, if you use square brace syntax to access characters by their offset or you use `str_split()`, you will get broken results when dealing with multibyte characters.

For anyone doing thorough research, I should also mention [the `\X` (unicode version of the dot)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903428/2943403) respects newline characters by default. `\X` is slightly different from `.` without the `s` modifier. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/CU4eH)

```
var_export(preg_split('/.\K/u', "å\nä", 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)); // element [1] has two characters in it!
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(preg_split('/.\K/us', "å\nä", 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(preg_split('/\X\K/u', "å\nä", 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of str_split function, you will do it.

Like below::

```
<?php 
$result = str_split('abcdef',1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str_split()` function

```
$array = str_split($string);

foreach ($array as $p){

    echo $p . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_split()` is not safe for multibyte characters.

`mb_str_split()` requires PHP 7.4+.

Try `preg_split()` for the rescuse:

```
$result = preg_split('/(.)/u', 'abcåäö', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the above ways and did not get results, try the following method. It worked for my language (Persian and Arabic):

```
$result = [];
for ( $i = 0; $i < mb_strlen( $string ); ++ $i ) {
    $result[] = mb_substr( $string, $i, 1, 'UTF-8' );
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Of course, it also works correctly for English. The point of this method is to use "mb_substr" along with "UTF-8" instead of "substr".