# PHP: Is it possible to change a character in a string with more than 1 character

Tags: php, string

Just wondering if it is possible to change a character in a string with more than 1 character. Here's my failed attempt:

```
<?
$string = abcde;
echo "character 2: ". $string[2] . "\n";
$string[2] = "X";
echo "character 2: ". $string[2] . "\n";
$string[2] = "moreThanOneChar";
echo "character 2: ". $string[2] . "\n";
echo "whole string: $string";
?>
```

output:

```
character 2: c
character 2: X
character 2: m      
whole string: abmde   // <-- This should be abmoreThanOneCharde
```

http://codepad.org/e2dDkH37

Comment: When using a string indexer (i.e. $string[2]) you are telling the interpreter you want a 'reference' to the second character of the string. This is a single character. Likewise, when you are setting a value to this indexer, you can only set a single character; therefore, you need a string replacement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using a regular expression (regex) replacement mechanism:

```
$string = preg_replace('/X/', 'moreThanOneChar', $string);
```

Note; however, that this will replace every instance of 'X' with 'moreThanOneChar'. If you want to limit this to only the first time, you can pass a limit as a fourth parameter:

```
$string = preg_replace('/X/', 'moreThanOneChar', $string, 1);
```

This can be easily expanded to replace phrases:

```
$string = 'Hello, man!';
$string = preg_replace('/man/', 'person', $string);

echo $string;
```

Output:

```
Hello, person!
```

Review the `preg_replace` command for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: doesn't it replace all the matches in the string? I mean in string "popeye" when you try to replace 3. char, you are not actually replacing all the "p"'s in the string.

Comment: It replaces as many matches as you specify, which is by default all of them, but you can set the limit in the fourth parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
function replaceInString($str, $pos, $substring)
{
     $part1 = substr($str, 0, -$pos);
     $part2 = substr($str, -$pos + 1);
     return $part1 . $substring . $part2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details):

> The string in PHP is implemented as an array of bytes and an integer indicating the length of the buffer.

So, while a string can be treated like an array of characters, it is not the same as other types of arrays where each element can be changed into a new data type.  Each element of a "string array" will always be a 1-byte character.

When you try to tell PHP "make this third character a string of other characters", PHP responds by saying "ok, but I'm going to only use the first character from the new string".

*Edit*

Some clarification after seeing the other answers.  I took your question to mean that you want to continue to access characters by location after the change.

For example:

```
$string = 'abcde';
echo $string[2];  //echoes c
$string[2] = 'fghi';
echo $string[2]:  //echoes fghi
```

This is simply not possible the way you describe.

If you really need functionality like that, [convert the string to an array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768314/convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters) and then operate on the array elements.