# php break string into characters

Tags: php, string

In PHP is there any function to break up string in to characters or array.

```
Example: OVERFLOW
```

I need to break up the above text OVERFLOW int to: `O V E R F L O W`

OR

```
    array( 
   0=> 'O',
    1=> 'V',
    2=> 'E',
    3=> 'R',
    4=> 'F',
    5=> 'L',
    6=> 'O',
    7=> 'W'
)
```

or any otherway is there..?

Comment: in php stings can be addressed as an array

Comment: Might I ask why? `$str = 'overflow'; echo $str[0];` echoes 'o' as it is. You can treat any string like an array without splitting it first anyhow

Comment: @Wooble Even though this can be easily found on google, it would still be best if the amount of questions on SO would grow, with more interesting questions with every day.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem  : I need a function.. because i need to separate lot of string this way.. so only.. otherwise i can find the string length and upto that string $str[n].. like that i can use by your way..

Comment: @think123 do you really like to answer the same questions over and over again and try to find something more interesting in a flood of the same, elementary, gazzilion-times-answered questions? this increases noise/signal ration in the bad direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a String into an Array of Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768314/convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters)

Comment: @Wooble yes, but if the question is not already on Stack Overflow, it would be good to populate the Stack Overflow database in a positive way.

Comment: @Wooble: I searched in stackoverflow but i could not found any solution so only i posted.. I not posted blindly :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String into an Array of Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768314/convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function for  this: [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split)

```
$broken = str_split("OVERFLOW", 1);
```

If your string can contain multi byte characters, use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) instead:

```
$broken = preg_split('##u', 'OVERFLOW', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 5):

use this function --- str_split();

This will split the string into character array.

Example:

```
$word="overflow";
$split_word=str_split($word);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this....

```
$var = "OVERFLOW";
echo $var[0]; // Will print "O".
echo $var[1]; // Will print "V".
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
$str = "OVERFLOW" ;
$var = str_split($str, 1);
var_dump($var);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'O' (length=1)
  1 => string 'V' (length=1)
  2 => string 'E' (length=1)
  3 => string 'R' (length=1)
  4 => string 'F' (length=1)
  5 => string 'L' (length=1)
  6 => string 'O' (length=1)
  7 => string 'W' (length=1)
```

Example

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$string = "your string";
$charArray = str_split($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**str_split**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

You can use it like this:

```
array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell you the truth, it already is broken up. So this would work:

```
$string = 'Hello I am the string.';
echo $string[0]; // 'H'
```

If you specifically want to split it, you could do this:

```
$string = 'Hello I am the string.';
$stringarr = str_split($string);
```

Depends if you really need to split it or not.