# Split MB string based on length

Tags: php, regex, string, function

I have a string which is in special language character.

```
先秦兩漢先秦兩漢先秦兩漢漢先秦兩漢漢先秦兩漢( 243071)
```

My requirement is to make it an array in case the character limit exceeds my requirement using php. Like if it exceeds say 15 characters.

For that, I have tried

```
if(mb_strlen($string) > 15){

    $seed = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

But it is breaking. It is not breaking for all the cases but for the one has 35 chars.

Another approach I have tried is using this function:-

```
function word_chunk($str, $len = 76, $end = "||") {
                        $pattern = '~.{1,' . $len . '}~u'; // like "~.{1,76}~u"
                        $str = preg_replace($pattern, '$0' . $end, $str);
                        return rtrim($str, $end);
            }
```

Please help and understand that I need help for MB characters only

Comment: Show us a sample input string (or three) and expected output.

Comment: Actually, i cannot because it is in the other language and I do not know how much confidential the content is. And I am not able to read that language I am just a coder you know :)

Comment: Are you looking for a multi-byte [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) equivalent? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988494/487813 ?

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue and understand your expected result then?  This is a criteria for on topic questions.

Comment: not word wrap but str_split equivalent str_split($str, 3); but MB do not have the ability to give me range param

Comment: I have updated my question with text, I have no clue what that means

Comment: @Gagandeep I think you should keep the `if(mb_strlen($string) > 15)` condition, and if it is true, use `preg_match_all('~\X~u', $str, $arr); return $arr[0];`. See [**this PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/F3Fq9).

Comment: See [**this PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/F3Fq9).

Comment: If you need an output like in mickmackusa's answer, see [**this PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/mt6Vm)

Comment: Actually, when I checked the code in the snippet checker it is working fine, but when I execute my csv in which there are many rows its breaking and showing this
This page isn’t working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will split your string after every 10th "extended grapheme cluster" (suggested by Wiktor up in the comments).

```
var_export(preg_split('~\X{10}\K~u', $string));
```

`preg_split('~.{10}\K~u', $string)` will work on your sample string, but for cases beyond yours, `\X` is more robust when dealing with unicode.

From https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html:

> You can consider \X the Unicode version of the dot. There is one difference, though: \X always matches line break characters, whereas the dot does not match line break characters unless you enable the dot matches newline matching mode.

Here is [a related SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928505/what-does-the-expression-x-match-when-inside-a-regex).

The `\K` restarts the fullstring match, so there are no characters lost in the split.

Here is a demo where `$len=10`  https://regex101.com/r/uO6ur9/2

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c32f881125518ccc4ece30d82b6807cbf0ee54d))

```
$string='先秦兩漢先秦兩漢先秦兩漢漢先秦兩漢漢先秦兩漢( 243071)';
var_export(preg_split('~\X{10}\K~u',$string,));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '先秦兩漢先秦兩漢先秦',
  1 => '兩漢漢先秦兩漢漢先秦',
  2 => '兩漢( 243071',
  3 => ')',
)
```

Implementation:

```
function word_chunk($str,$len){
    return preg_split('~\X{'.$len.'}\K~u',$str);
}
```

While `preg_split()` might be slightly slower than `preg_match_all()`, one advantage is that `preg_split()` provides the desired 1-dimensional array.  `preg_match_all()` generates a multi-dimensional array by which you would only need to access the `[0]` subarray's elements.

Comment: $seed = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
-- what is the difference, please explain?

Comment: That will split on every mb character: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c15f2f40df93535e24f7179cd551ef9d8681228

Comment: I see the tester website for regex, can I test my actual text there, and how do I know if my text is working fine? Please help

Comment: just a sec you are fast, let me test

Comment: I am quite confident it is working, let me test finally on my dev instance

Comment: Can you please make it like a function like i wrote in my question?

Comment: function word_chunk($str) {
         
         $array = preg_split('~.{1,20}\K~u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
         return $array;
   }

Comment: 1 for the help so far

Comment: As I said the code is working when I run it individually, but my CSV is breaking, I think my magento code is breaking somewhere

Comment: Worked, in the end the issue was my laziness. I ctrl+H and tried to explode all ** with ||, which turn out that the comment which is above function was also changed, so my PHP file was not executing properly.